# gene expression analysis in two groups

Tags: statistics, expression, linear-regression

I'm analyzing gene expression data from an experiment where I have:
(i) two groups of normal and patient samples;
(ii) for different number of genes ranging from 25000 to 130000 that majority of values are zero;
(iii) the values for different cases are in several files and not just one.

I'm trying to find genes with differential expression between two groups. No idea what script to use?

Comment: Please specify which you tools you have available (or want to use) and what knowledge of programming languages you have. This kind of problem could be solved with any kind of language (e.g. `C++/Cuda/OpenCL` for performance, functional languages or script languages for accessibility). The range of math tools is even larger.

Comment: thanks Rio for the reply, I have very basic knowledge of programming as I am a biologist! I think for the data that I have I need the scripts for heatmap analysis, I need to see what genes are up- or down-regulated between two sets of samples?